# How to send nested object data as post data using curl command in shell script?

Tags: bash, shell, curl

I am trying to send a post request using curl command in shell script.

When i run this curl command in terminal, it is working fine.

```
curl -d '{"DataArr":[{"serialno":"ab1","filePath":"/home/name/notes1"}]}' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Authorization: tasfdgfdhh...' http://localhost:8081/create
```

The same I am trying to run this as shell script file, it is hitting the server but the data format is not expected. The array bracket is converting as :" or something like :{  . I tried so many times with different possibilities but i do not understand how to prepare correct request. Below is the code and the response at server side.

I am using looping statement to simulate multiple requests,

```
code:
#!/bin/bash
echo "hello welcome to testing";
token=asdghadjakalskl.....

requestNo=10
i=0
sNo=(ab1 ab2 ab3 ab4 ab5)
fn=(notes1 Pictures/crop.jpeg Pictures/cat.jpeg Pictures/mountain.jpg Pictures/magic.jpeg Pictures/tree.jpg)

echo $1

for (( i=0; i< $1;i++ ))
do
    # echo "welcome inside the loop $s"
    
    echo ${sNo[i%5]} ${fn[i%6]}
    f="/home/name/${fn[i%6]}"
    # echo $token
    echo file $f
    echo $i request sent
   
    curl -d '{"DataArr":[{"serialno":'${sNo[i%5]}',"filePath":'$f'}]}' -H "'Content-Type: application/json'" -H 'Authorization: '$token'' http://localhost:8080/create

    
done
```

At server side,

```
{"{\"qualityDataArr\":":{"{\"serialNumberCustomer\":ab1,\"filePath\":/home/name/notes1}":""}}
```

Please guide me.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try `echo """'{\"DataArr\":[{\"serialno\":\"${sNo[i%5]}\",\"filePath\":\"$f\"}]}'"""`
and if it displays well, then use `echo curl -d """'{\"DataArr\":[{\"serialno\":\"${sNo[i%5]}\",\"filePath\":\"$f\"}]}'""" -H "'Content-Type: application/json'" -H """'Authorization: $token'""" http://localhost:8080/create | bash`

Comment: Thank you Necklondon! Its working.

the below one also working.
"'{\"DataArr\":[{\"serialno\":\"${sNo[i%5]}\",\"filePath\":\"$f\"}]}'"

Answer (score 0):

There are some issues with the `curl` command here that I would prefer to approach slightly differently.

The first issue is the preparation of the JSON.

With `'{"DataArr":[{"serialno":'${sNo[i%5]}',"filePath":'$f'}]}'`, the resulting JSON has a problem.  The values for `serialno` and `filePath` looks likely alphanumeric or may contain spaces, meaning the values would need to be double quoted, eg `"filePath": "/path/to/some where/to/new note"`, and this is not handled.

I would suggest to prepare the JSON using `jq` and store in a shell variable for later use with `curl -d`. Example,

```
jq --null-input               \
   --arg serialno ${sNo[i%5]} \
   --arg filePath $f          \
   '{"DataArr": [{"serialno": $serialno,"filePath": $filePath}]}'
```

`--null-input` is used because we wants to construct JSON data from scratch

`--arg name value` allows us to pass a string value to `jq` as a predefined variable.

This will for example gives you the following well formed JSON:

```
{
  "dataarr": [
    {
      "serialno": "ab1",
      "filepath": "/home/name/notes1"
    }
  ]
}
```

And this well formed JSON can be stored in a shell variable for later use:

```
prepared_payload=$( jq --null-input               \
                       --arg serialno ${sNo[i%5]} \
                       --arg filePath $f          \
                       '{"DataArr": [{"serialno": $serialno,"filePath": $filePath}]}' )
```

Now we can use this `prepared_payload`, like `curl -d "${prepared_payload}"`

The next issue is the inappropriate usage of single and double quotes in `curl` header options `-H "'Content-Type: application/json'"` and `-H 'Authorization: '$token''`

There are related past questions/answers, that can be helpful to take a deeper look at,

[Difference between single and double quotes in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash)
https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Single-Quotes.html
https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Double-Quotes.html

The preferred approach would be `-H "Content-Type: application/json"` and `-H "Authorization: $token"`

The end `curl` command would thus looks as follows:

```
prepared_payload=$( jq --null-input               \
                       --arg serialno ${sNo[i%5]} \
                       --arg filePath $f          \
                       '{"DataArr": [{"serialno": $serialno,"filePath": $filePath}]}' )

curl -d "${prepared_payload}" -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
                              -H "Authorization: $token"          \
                              http://localhost:8080/create
```